# STPPaymentContext Language (iOS)

Tags: ios, localization, stripe-payments

Following the "Standard iOS Integration Guide", I can customize the Stripe UI elements as e.g. the theme color, etc.
https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/standard

Is there a possibility to edit the actual text of the default UI elements? My goal is to make the interface adaptable to different languages.

I thank you for any help!